# Constructing URLs with a list of words and downloading from the URLs with command line

Tags: shell-script, wget

Suppose I have a list of words in a text file e.g:

> abstinence ; abuse ; academic ; accommodate ; accommodation ;
>   accommodationist ; accomplice ; accomplish ; accord ; account ;
>   accountable ; acquiescence ; acrimonious ; acronym

I want to change each word to a URL and download the file using commands in a terminal window. For example the first word from the list, that is, `abstinence` will change into `https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/abstinence.mp3` and the file `abstinence.mp3` will be downloaded into a folder. Then the next word, that is, `abuse` will change into the url `https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/abuse.mp3` and the file `abuse.mp3` will be downloaded from the url and so on.

Can it be done using commad line in terminal or using a script run in command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily:

```
while read -d ';' word; do 
    wget "https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/$word.mp3"; 
done < file
```

#### Explanation

`while read -d';' word` will read each line from `file`, and save each `;`-separated word (because of `-d';'`) as `$word`. This is then passed to `wget` which downloads the file.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
for word in $(tr -d \; < wordlist.txt); do
   wget https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/$word.mp3
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On BSD/OS X

```
sed -i '' 's/;/\
/g' mp3.txt && sed -i '' s'/^/wget\ https:\/\/ssl.gstatic.com\/dictionary\/static\/sounds\/de\/0\//g' mp3.txt && sed -i '' s'/$/.mp3/g' mp3.txt && chmod +x mp3.txt && ./mp3.txt
```

using `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

To download a list of files, you can use `wget -i file`, where *`file`* is the name of a file with a list of URL(s) to download.

For more details you can review the help page: `man wget`.

Constructing such a list of URLs from your list of words is easily done
with text processing tools like `sed`.